# Use github library with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I am currently using a library found on github, which our client is updating daily.

Right now, I have cloned the repository, imported the project as a separate module, and I have been able to use it just fine.

However, when the client updates the library, I have to sync, remove the module from my project, and add the updated one.

I should mention that I have to use the github app, cannot use the system embedded in Android Studio.

Is there a way to do this better?

Answer (score 1):

> imported the project as a separate module

If, in addition of declaring it as a "module", you import that project as a **[git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**, then you can [make that submodule follow a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309), and a simple `git submodule update --remote` would be enough to update the project sources.